# AngularJS 1.5 Toggle class method

Tags: angularjs, toggleclass, using-directives

I'm trying to do a `toggleClass onClick` in AngularJs 1.5. Is there any possibility to do that? For example, if you click on a div it'll change a background color.

Comment: You could simply use `ng-class` directive as shown in below answer..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-class` which is made for this very purpose.

`ng-class` is used like `<div ng-class={'class_you_want_to_apply': some_boolean_variable}></div>`

If you want to add more classes you can do so by added commas after each 'some_boolean_variable'

More docs at:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass